# Rails custom form action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a few forms on a page - I want each to be pushed to a custom controller action.

Each form is going to upload an image (an avatar, a background image, etc), and I want each form to use a different controller action - however, I'm getting 404 errors.

```
<%= form_for @shap, :remote => true, :url => {:action => 'upload_avatar'}, :html => {:id => 'edit_shop_2'} do |f| %>
     <%= f.file_field :avatar, :class=>'avatar_upload' %>
<% end %>
```

I have the route properly defined, a controller action, and associated javascript file to return on success. Why the 404?

Answer (score 0):

you also need to define controller name here

```
<%= form_for @shap, :url => {:controller=>"your controller", :action => 'upload_avatar'}, :remote => true, :html => {:id => 'edit_shop_2'} do |f| %>
     <%= f.file_field :avatar, :class=>'avatar_upload' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It defaults to the proper controller based on the @shap object - defining the controller explicitly results in the same errors, unfortunately!

Comment: then check your logs......otherwise show your logs where you are getting the 404 error